# Is it possible to embed a C compiler in an iPad app?

Tags: ios

I'm going to travel soon, and I'd like to be able to develop in C on my iPad. I know that Apple won't let an app like this into the store, but it is useful for me. So the question is how to put the C compiler in the app, and how to be able to run programs there?

Comment: Jailbreak your iPad, then install whatever compiler you wish.  Or, better yet, use an actual computer without a walled garden and that comes with a physical keyboard.

Comment: http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/9553/2076 & http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/codetogo/id382677229?mt=8

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest using a SSH connection app to connect to a computer with access to a C programming environment and compiler. This does require use of a second computer, but its not too difficult to set up and allows access to other utilities as well. I have used this in the past on my iPhone, so I can confirm it works. There are a number of SSH / VPN apps on the App store, but I cannot recommend one in particular for iPad. Unlike the Code2Go app, this can be free.
Hope this helps.

Comment: I have no 3G, so I will jailbreak the iPad and follow the instructions of this link http://blog.syshalt.net/index.php/2010/09/12/compile-c-applications-with-gcc-on-ios-4-iphone/

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to jailbreak your iDevice (there are plenty of step-by-step tutorials for doing so in the web) and then, launch the Cydia store, once in Cydia look for the "Development" section and install the `GNU C Compiler`, once the compiler is installed in your iDevice, establish a ssh connection (using Putty on windows or typing ssh in a terminal on linux) edit your sources in your favorite editor and upload them by ssh (using WinSCP on Windows or typing scp in a terminal on linux)

Once you have uploaded your files, invoke the compilation commands in the ssh session you already established over your iDevice, you should be able to edit/upload/compile/fix or run your programs in the device without Apple restrictions

Post a comment if you need more details for the whole process